# Send MKMapKit coordinates to Google Maps APP

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-maps, mapkit

I have an projetc with a MapKit and one Pin, I need send the pin's coordinate to the google maps APP, Somebody knows how to do it?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean the Maps App (yes, it's powered by Google Maps, but it's written by Apple), then the following will work:

```
- (void)openMapToLatitude:(double)lat longitude:(double) lon
{
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=%f,%f", lat, lon];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

}
```

The URL is intercepted by the OS and opened in Maps.

Comment: you know how to open this coordinates dropping an pin at this coordinate? thanks!

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can't tell Maps to drop a pin at that point.

Comment: I discovered how to do this, just put the URL like this:  http:../maps?q=%f,%f